# About Android resources and screen densities

Tags: android, dpi, screen-size

I am developing android apps for years now, and I always struggled with the part of resizing all icons for all different screen densities. 
A couple of days ago I developed a utility for making this task easy and released it's source. But I received the following comment:

"If you have a mdpi device, and an app only has xhdpi resources, the system will scale the xhdpi resources down to mdpi size automatically."

So, I should not create all icons in different sizes for all screen densities??? Have I been wasting effort and time all this years?

Comment: btw if someone is interested, the tool I developed is here:
https://github.com/asystat/Final-Android-Resizer

Comment: Well it is not useless for me, as I normally don't use 9-patch images in my apps. If you find it useless, then keep it for yourself instead of being a damn troll. You didn't even answer my question ¬¬

Comment: kid, i did not plan to answer your question. and there are tools that scale all pngs, including 9patch.got it now?

Comment: got it, "natural born IT professional"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Android scales your bitmap drawables (.png, .jpg, and .gif files) and Nine-Patch drawables (.9.png files) so that they render at the appropriate physical size on each device.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

But you did not wast effort and time because to ensure your bitmaps look their best, you should include alternative versions at different resolutions for different screen densities.
Also this will give better performance